# dynamic layout positioning in android studio

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, position

I am working on a food ordering app in android where I have to show a list of food items for users which they can add to cart. Lets say there are 5 items in the catalogue list (item1, item2, item3, item4, item5), when I click on item1 "add to cart" button, the view updates for item5. I am quite confused on where I am going wrong with this. I know it should update visually for item1 but not able to understand why it updates for the last item in the list. Here's my code block

```
addTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String tagValue = (String) v.getTag();
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(tagValue)) {

                        int position = Integer.parseInt(tagValue);
                        ProductKitchenViewDetailsResponseObject.Product_details details = productDetailsList.get(position);
                        String listPrice = details.getList_price();
                        String productID = details.getProduct_id();
                        String strQuantity = "1";
                  addTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
                  quantitylistlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);      }
                        Toast.makeText(KitchenListeningActivity.this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: could you show your 5 items, and how you set to them the click listeners?

Comment: addTextView is set in dynamic layout and click listeners also

Comment: well @Bharath Kumar I didn't ask what you do, I asked you to show the code. If you don't show the higher level code, very unlikely anyone could help you to solve this issue